# how can xss filtering in codeigniter 3 still usefull?

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter, xss, codeigniter-3

Hi I would like to know if should the use of this parameters still usefull and effective for security purposes.

```
$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE);
```

I'm not sure if I should put all my post data with the second parameter (TRUE). Is there a cons and pro using it for codeigniter 3 because if `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` is officially depreciated what will be the essence of using of that second parameter in the post?

Thanks!

Comment: Attempting to filter injection exploits out of input is bad practice. Instead, transform your data into the appropriate form for use by various components – for example, by using a template engine that automatically HTML-encodes output. Are you using a separate template engine right now, or just the built-in `<?php … ?>` one?

Comment: @Ryan using separate specifically smarty.net

Comment: @Ryan should I still use the second parameter for added security?

Comment: Probably not. It is too computationally expensive and as @Ryan said, "bad practice".  That said, you should always check input from users for 1. Validity - does the data meets certain qualifications; 2. It should be sanitized on an input by input basis. Read up on PHP's [data filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) and then - for some truely heavy reading - check out this on [Data Validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)

Comment: @DFriend thanks man! and to Ryan too :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the validation functions in `/system/libraries/Forum_validation.php`. Lots of valuable techniques for checking out user inputs. These techniques have value beyond form validation. Remember "user input" can also mean arguments passed in a URL to a controller and data sent via AJAX. Trust nothing from the outside world.

Comment: @DFriend didn't know that there is this validation in libraries. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DFriend is this correnct `$this->load->library('form_validation');
  $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email', 'required');
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   print_r('this is false');exit;
  }
  else
  {
   print_r('this is true');exit;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

XSS filtering is depreciated in the sense that you are using it. However you are advised to use

```
$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
```

This is to be used for submission and used at the time of submission

Look in the Security library.

Using form_open escapes your data, but data still should be  cleaned using

```
'title'   => html_escape(trim($this->input->post('title')))
```